Getting SSL violation of protocol error while trying to run truedata websocket on my ubuntu server
I'm getting this error when I try to run my truedata websocket python script on my ubuntu server deployed on E2E.
    ERROR:websocket:error from callback <bound method LiveClient.ws_open of <truedata_ws.websocket.TD_live.LiveClient object at 0x7efce88acee0>>: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:2426)

I was locally also getting this error but it got resolved by installing _(ndg-httpsclient, pyopenssl, pyasn1)_ these python libraries. But the same didn't work on server.
Also, tried to disable the firewall on server and run, still didn't work.
I do not have any security configured on my server.
How do I resolve it ?
